# How to update a document in MongoDB without inserting duplicate entry?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have these docs in my collection.

```
{"_id": 1, "name": "Banana, "quantity": 3}
{"_id": 2, "name": "Apple, "quantity": 4}
{"_id": 3, "name": "Orange, "quantity": 5}
```

Now I need to edit the 2nd doc in the collection.

```
var doc = {"_id": 2}
var updateQuery = {"_id": 2, "name": "Banana", "quantity": 4}
var dataModified = { $set: updateQuery };
```

and use the updateOne query,

```
db.collection.updateOne(doc, dataModified)
```

This works fine. But this will add the duplicate entry of "**Banana**" in the docs. Like this:

```
{"_id": 1, "name": "Banana, "quantity": 3}
{"_id": 2, "name": "Banana, "quantity": 4}
{"_id": 3, "name": "Orange, "quantity": 5}
```

So is there anyway, I could find out/restrict the duplicate entry of `"name"` field while updating the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#create-a-unique-index) on `name` field and you'll get an exception when you try to insert duplicated value:

```
db.members.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```